# Switching between .ui and .cpp in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, ide, qt-creator

In Qt Creator, is there an easy way to directly switch between the Design view and the .cpp file associated with the form (and vice-versa)?

When I go from Design mode to Edit mode (Ctrl-2), it annoyingly shows me the XML code of the .ui file, so I have to manually pick the .cpp file.

When I'm in the .cpp file of a form, the Design mode icon and shortcut (Ctrl-3) are disabled, so I have to manually pick the .ui file.

There must be a better way to switch between ui <--> cpp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buried in the menu, is the `Tools -> Form Editor -> Switch Source / Form` command. It has the Shift-F4 hotkey and does exactly what I was looking for.

F7 doesn't seem to be bound to any command, so I rebound the  `FormEditor/FormSwitchSource` command to use F7 as the keyboard shortcut. I can now switch between ui <--> cpp with a single keypress!

**EDIT:**

There's a known [bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-4264) with Qt Creator where it doesn't save the keyboard shortcut for the `FormEditor/FormSwitchSource` command.